# Least complete Solutions

Tags: number-theory

I know what least residues are and I can solve them, but apparently, for an equation like this:
$$x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 195,$$
you have to find the least complete solutions.

I tried looking for an example online but couldn't find anything. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$195=3\cdot 5\cdot 13 \mid x^2+x+1$ implies $5\mid x^2+x+1$. The polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$, in particular it has no root in $\mathbb{F}_5$. Indeed, just try all elements of $\mathbb{F}_5$. So there is no solution modulo $195$ (there is a solution modulo $3$ with $x=1$, and a solution modulo $13$ with $x=3$ or $x=9$).

Answer (score 1):

Since the modulus is composite, you solve the equation mod $3,5,13$ then combine with the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  The moduli are so small you can do it by inspection (i.e. trying each number in turn).